# How to import data from sybase by sqoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop, sybase-ase15

I am able to import data from oracle 11g by sqoop using following command

```
import"
                , "-fs",  "file:///"
                , "-jt", "local"
                , "-libjars", "/tmp/HELLO/tej01/EMP.jar"
                , "--connect", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.111:1522:test"
                , "--username", "SCOTT", "--password", "password"
                ,"--table","EMP"
                ,"--inline-lob-limit","0"
                , "-m", "1"
                ,"--target-dir","/tmp/HELLO/tej01"
                ,"--fields-terminated-by", "^"
                , "--enclosed-by", enclosedBY
```

Now I am trying to import data of sybase-ase by using sqoop. For this I used following command -

```
sqoop import --verbose --connect jdbc:sybase:Tds:[host]:5000?ServiceName=master --username sa --password password --query  "select * from City where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /tmp/HELLO/tej01 --driver "com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver" -m 1
```

But I am getting following error -

```
    ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://[host]:54310/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-format-2.0.0.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:269)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importQuery(SqlManager.java:729)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:499)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

And this jar file is already in lib folder of sqoop.
Please help me.
I am using

Hadoop version : 2.6.0

Sqoop version : 1.4.6

Comment: As per the error message, /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-format-2.0.0.jar file is missing in the HDFS. Can you execute 
hadoop -put  /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-format-2.0.0.jar  /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-format-2.0.0.jar
and execute the same command and paste the output

Comment: Thanks for your reply.parquet-format-2.0.0.jar file is already in the lib folder of sqoop and still I get this error.

Comment: What I meant was this file is expected in hdfs. Can you just execute the command that I sent in the other message

Comment: I have execute as you have told me above and found that command prompt window stucked from this line -  `INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select * from City where  (1 = 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved with following command

```
sqoop import --verbose --connect jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.1.102:5000?ServiceName=master --username sa --password password --table Class --driver com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver -m 1 --target-dir file:////tmp/HELLO/tej01
```

Comment: excuse my ignorance but where does sqoop save this file to?